# Sample space for combinations versus permutations

Tags: statistics

A bag contains 3 toys: 1 yellow, 1 green, and 1 orange. An experiment involves taking 1 toy from the bag, replacing it, and drawing a second toy.

I'm confused as to how I describe the sample space when order does not matter versus when it does.

When order doesn't matter, I think that's considered a combination. Would the sample space therefore be S = {(YY),(YG),(YO),(GG),(GO),(OO)} since redundant outcomes are removed (e.g., YG == GY)?

To that end, the sample space would be of size 9 when order does matter since redundant events are included.

Is my reasoning correct? Should redundant events be omitted, or should the sample space always include every possible outcome (even if they are redundant)?